# Trace theorem for Sobolev functions: what is the significance of continuous extension to the boundary?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Why in the proof of the trace theorem in L.C.Evans' book on PDE, he has considered functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\bigcap C(\overline{\Omega})$ when it is enough to choose functions in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, which tackles a bigger issue?.

Comment: Please reformulate your question. For me, it is hard (if not even impossible) to understand what you actually want to know.

Comment: PhoemueX... I was trying to know why do we consider $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\bigcap C(\overline{\Omega})$ instead of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?.

Answer (score 2):

The trace theorem, as stated by Evans:

> Assume $U$ is bounded and $\partial U$ is $C^1$. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $T:W^{1,p}(U)\to L^p(\partial U)$ such that
>
> 1. $Tu=u_{|\partial U}$ if $u\in W^{1,p}(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$
> 2. $\|Tu\|_{L^p(\partial U)}\le C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$ for all $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, with $C$ depending only on $p$ and $U$.

The theorem deals with the entire space $ W^{1,p}(U)$: the trace operator $T$ is defined and studied on this space. Property (1) says that the concept of trace offered by this operator agrees with the restriction to the boundary *when the latter is defined*. For functions that don't have a continuous extension to the boundary, we don't have $u_{|\partial U}$ to talk about.

To summarize: the theorem defines the trace for *every* Sobolev function. Part 1 is just a consistency check, which we can do only when there is another concept of boundary values available.

Comment: For example, if you drop condition 1, there is no guarantee that T is at all a reasonable notion of "take the boundary value". Taking T=0 would satisfy condition 2.

Comment: Thank you very much 900 sit-ups a day and Nate Elredge. :). Got it...was confused for quite long.